# Dynamic type fields and allocations in C# (.NET Core 2.0)

Tags: c#, dynamic, benchmarking, allocation, expandoobject

I'm trying to understand why declaring a private field as dynamic and then using it as a parameter for a function would cause several memory allocations when calling that function later; while if I declare the field as an object it seems to cause no allocations at all. The function's parameter type is still dynamic for both cases.

I made the tests using Visual Studio 2019 and its .NET Object Allocation Tracking profiler, on a .NET Core 2.2 console program.

**First Test**:
The field *_state* is declared as dynamic type.

```
    public class DynamicStateBenchmark
    {
        private dynamic _state;
        private Func<dynamic, bool> _conditional;

        public void Setup()
        {
            _state = new ExpandoObject();
            _state.A = true;

            _conditional = s => s.A;

            _conditional(_state);
        }

        public void Execute()
        {
            _conditional(_state);
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var benchmark = new DynamicStateBenchmark();
            benchmark.Setup();
            benchmark.Execute();
        }
    }
```

**Results:**
Several allocations made inside the *Execute()* method.

[image]

**Second Test:**
The field *_state* is declared as object type.

```
    public class DynamicStateBenchmark
    {
        private object _state;
        private Func<dynamic, bool> _conditional;

        public void Setup()
        {
            dynamic state = new ExpandoObject();
            state.A = true;
            _state = state;

            _conditional = s => s.A;

            _conditional(_state);
        }

        public void Execute()
        {
            _conditional(_state);
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var benchmark = new DynamicStateBenchmark();
            benchmark.Setup();
            benchmark.Execute();
        }
    }
```

**Results:**
No allocations inside the *Execute()* method.

[image]